# How do I get rid of one intellisense warning in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

[image]

I have the above directory structure in python and code works fine.
But Visual Code thinks there is a problem. How do I disable this specific warning?

Comment: Are you sure it works properly? Don't you need `from mylib import app_database as db` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sys.path.insert() will probably work, it is a rather **"hacky"** solution. And one reason for that is that a linter can't verify upfront, if the subsequent import will work: The sys.path will change at runtime only. This seems to be no problem for the author himself, but in case he needs to collaborate with other Python developers some day, they will most likely first check the linter report of his code before they pull it into their repository.

"**Clean coding**" is different, but no magic at all. Use editable installs to make you package behave like in the target install:

```
pip install -e mypackage
```

However, this requires a minimal *setup.py* in the mypackage root folder with

```
import setuptools   
setuptools.setup(name='mypackage')
```

You could also try adding the **no-quality-assistance** (noqa) flag to the end of your import statement via

```
import app_database as db  #noqa
```

but I would not recommend doing that.

Comment: You could also try adding the no-quality-assitance flag to the end of your import statement via `import mysecret  #noqa`, but I would not recommend doing that

Comment: import setuptools is a good idea, but here we are just building a small application to be used by a few people. #noqa does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The intelligence analyser offers basic detection. So you can disable it by following settings

```
"python.analysis.disabled": [
    "use-before-def"
]
```

Doc:- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_python-language-server-settings